# NoClassDefFoundError in Spring Boot fat jar but dependency is in compiled archive and application runs fine in IDE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, uberjar

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

For some reason, the class loader that I was using to load my custom class, which extends `GenModel`, did not have the context of the classes that were already loaded, which I did not anticipate.  So, even though `GenModel` was loaded from my debugging perspective, it was not loaded from my `modelLoader`'s perspective.

**Solution**: `URLClassLoader` instances can be handed a parent context. Not knowing exactly which context to hand it, I just retrieved the context of the `GenModel` class I knew to be already loaded, figuring that that context would obviously contain `GenModel`.  So, in the end I only changed one line of code:

```
URLClassLoader modelLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{modelURL});
```

became

```
URLClassLoader modelLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{modelURL},GenModel.class.getClassLoader());
```

and that solved it!

Shout out to @EvilToad, who put me on the right track through his comments!

**ORIGINAL ISSUE:**

I am building a prototype that implements compiled h2o neural network models as web services, injecting the model at runtime. The app runs in a Spring Boot embedded Tomcat server and is a Maven project. I have the following dependency in the Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2o-genmodel</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency includes the class `hex.genmodel.GenModel`.
When the application starts, it loads the custom model class using a `URLClassLoader` and casts it as a `GenModel`.  The relevant code is as follows:

```
import hex.genmodel.GenModel;
```

...

```
@Bean
public NeuralNetPredictor neuralNetPredictor() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    URL modelURL = (new File(this.modelJarPath)).toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader modelLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{modelURL});
    GenModel rawModel = (GenModel) modelLoader.loadClass(this.modelClassName).newInstance();
    modelLoader.close();

    return new NeuralNetPredictor(rawModel, this.modelClassName);
}
```

And here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TVGML</groupId>
    <artifactId>neuralnetpredictor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2o-genmodel</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I make and run the application using the following IntelliJ configuration, everything runs great:

[IntelliJ run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcbDS.png)

Everything loads, the server comes up as expected, all functionality works, etc.

On the other hand, if I do a `mvn clean install` or `package` that also builds fine, but when I run `java -jar <myjarartifact>`, the application throws an exception:

...`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.----.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor]: Factory method 'neuralNetPredictor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel`

...`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel`

...`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hex.genmodel.GenModel`

Here's the part that throws me off: when I look inside the fat jar produced by spring boot, hex.genmodel.GenModel is there, no different from the other dependencies:

[GenModel class in fat jar dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUc9x.png)

UPDATED:
Here's the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/model': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictorController.pred; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neuralNetPredictor' defined in com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor]: Factory method 'neuralNetPredictor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService.main(NeuralNetService.java:34)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictorController.pred; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neuralNetPredictor' defined in com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor]: Factory method 'neuralNetPredictor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neuralNetPredictor' defined in com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor]: Factory method 'neuralNetPredictor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetPredictor]: Factory method 'neuralNetPredictor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService.neuralNetPredictor(NeuralNetService.java:46)
    at com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$352d44ca.CGLIB$neuralNetPredictor$0(<generated>)
    at com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$352d44ca$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$21caa282.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.NeuralNetService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$352d44ca.neuralNetPredictor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hex.genmodel.GenModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 60 more
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be missing from the manifest even if the JAR appears in the fat JAR?

Comment: I suspect that `this.modelClassName` is `hex.genmodel.GenModel`, right? And that the exception is thrown when `modelLoader.loadClass` is called, right? (More details on that would be appreciated, like more stack trace with line numbers). If what I suppose is right, the problem probably lies with the `URLClassLoader`: it is not able to locate the JAR. First I would try to understand why the application works when you run it in your IDE, while in debug. Place a breakpoint after `modelLoader` is created in both cases and try to find what's different (a relative file path, maybe?)

Comment: The manifest only mentions spring boot and my main class.  However, there are lots of other dependencies that are working fine but are not mentioned.Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
    Built-By: NLUCERO
    Start-Class: com.-------.research.machinelearning.neuralnets.
 NeuralNetService
    Spring-Boot-Version: 1.3.5.RELEASE
    Created-By: Apache Maven
    Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_65
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: @EvilToad.  No, the model class name `this.modelClassName` is the custom generated neural net model.  In this case `deeplearning_bcc078fd_abba_4f9c_8e5b_7628051ddeda`.  That class is being supplied by the URLClassLoader and is, surprisingly, working fine.  As mentioned, this code runs great inside of Eclipse.

One thing I did try was to move the cast to (GenModel) later in the code, to isolate the very thing that you're getting at.  The same problem persists.  The issue is with `hex.genmodel.GenModel`, not with `this.modelClassName` (a different class).  Stack trace posted now.

Comment: Then try to inspect `rawModel.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` while in debug in Eclipse. This should give you the physical location of the class source and, hopefully, an idea about why it does not find the class in the other case.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, the problem does arise from the URLClassLoader (`...Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hex.genmodel.GenModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)...`).

Comment: @EvilToad. Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately still no dice.  I get `file:/C:/Users/-----/Documents/Dev/goalsNet.jar`, which is where I would expect the injected  `deeplearning_bcc078fd_abba_4f9c_8e5b_7628051ddeda` to come from.  rawModel is the model that gets injected via args. `--model-jar-path=C:\\Users\\-----\\Documents\\Dev\\goalsNet.jar`

Comment: @EvilToad, you're right.  The error is being thrown from inside of findClass.  The class that I'm dynamically loading extends GenModel.  And, while the context from which I'm retrieving that class has GenModel (I inspected it and it's coming from the fat JAR as expected), my hypothesis is that the class I'm importing isn't seeing GenModel in its context.  I'm not sure how to let it know where to find it.  Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Maybe add all the required JARs when you create the URLClassLoader. Beware of ClassCastException and LinkageError, though: classes loaded by different class loaders are NOT the same to the JVM.

Comment: @EvilToad, I solved it! You helped a ton.  Updating post now.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

URLClassLoader instances can be handed a parent context. Not knowing exactly which context to hand it, I just retrieved the context of the GenModel class I knew to be already loaded, figuring that that context would obviously contain GenModel. So, in the end I only changed one line of code:

```
URLClassLoader modelLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{modelURL});
```

became

```
URLClassLoader modelLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{modelURL},GenModel.class.getClassLoader());
```

and that solved it!

Shout out to @EvilToad, who put me on the right track through his comments!